# If else on array but only run the else statement once, not every time the return is false

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array and a name

```
var name = "Karen"

var arr = [ 
"Karen",
"Ronald",
"Mcdonald"
];

// Code here
```

I want to check if `name` is indexed in `arr`.
If it is then `console.log(true)` but if not I only want to `console.log(false);` one time.
I'm logging false every time the name doesn't match that is my problem.

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: Sounds like you want `console.log(arr.includes(name))`. That will log only once; `true` if `name` is in the array, `false` otherwise. See [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Answer (score 0):

It seems simple enough.

```js
const name = "Karen"

var arr = [
"Karen",
"Ronald",
"Mcdonald"
];
if (arr.indexOf(name) > -1) {
  console.log(true);
} else {
  console.log(false);
}
```

Or `Array.prototype.some`:

```js
var name = "Karen";

var arr = [
"Karen",
"Ronald",
"Mcdonald"
];
console.log(arr.some(n => n == name))
```

[MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: `? true : false` is redundant. Also, why suggest `some` and `indexOf`, but not `includes`?

Comment: `includes` will return if the array includes anything (e.g., `["Value"].includes("a"); // true`; as with `["Value"].indexOf("a") > -1; // false`;)

Comment: `[ "Value" ].includes("a")` is `false`.

Comment: @ParkingMaster you seem to be confusing `String.prototype.includes()` and `Array.prototype.includes()`.

Comment: @Phil so that means then you should use indexOf

Comment: For this, no. I'd use `arr.includes(name)`. I also wouldn't use a redundant ternary

Comment: @ParkingMaster It’s advisable to follow the documentation again: [`Array.prototype.includes`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes), [`String.prototype.includes`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes). Don’t accidentally coerce an array to a string, if that’s what you had in mind.

Comment: @Phil I use `true : false` because if it returns something like `null` or `undefined` it'll be logged as `false`.

Comment: But [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some#return_value) **only** returns a Boolean 

Comment: @ParkingMaster Again, the documentation is right here: [`Array.prototype.some`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some#return_value). _“Return value: `true` if the callback function returns a truthy value for at least one element in the array. Otherwise, `false`.”_. Note how `null` or `undefined` aren’t options. If in doubt, the [specification](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.some) is more detailed. Theoretically, `some` can throw a TypeError, but its only possible return value is a boolean.